# Disable Home/Key trigger browser scrolling top/bottom when typing in input field/textarea

Tags: google-chrome, macos

It's normal to use <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> to move cursor to beginning/end of line when typing.

But, recently this two key on my Chrome/Safari will trigger browser scrolling top/bottom when typing in input field/text area.

It will scroll first, and if I press <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> again it will trigger the "move cursor"

How to fix this?

Comment: 'Normal' where? That sounds more like Windows behaviour to me. Mac behaviour scrolls the screen but doesn't move the cursor. Cmd/arrow moves the cursor.

Comment: This is a real pain for me too. MBP 2021/Ventura - just migrated from Monterey where it did not happen. github, Notion, even google, have become considerably harder to use without home/end.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue solved:**

- Install [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)
- Import rules from site - [Windows shortcuts on MacOS](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=Windows%20shortcuts%20on%20MacOS)
- Activate shortcuts:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using hammerspoon, just tack this onto the end of your `init.lua`:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "home", 
    function()
        hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "left")
    end
)
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "end", 
    function()
        hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "right")
    end
)
```

Comment: More info here, if you really want to turbo charge your OSX XP: https://www.hammerspoon.org/